# OEM disk image?

Tags: system-installation, 20.04, oem

Are somewhere available Ubuntu OEM disk image (not iso) to be downloaded and flashed on an external drive?
I know, maybe dumb request, but I now need to prepare an external usb SSD to work on to avoid dual boot my system.
Even an Ubuntu like distro will be fine.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you need from an "OEM disk image"? Why can't it be an ISO?

Comment: Because if I decided to install ubuntu on a secondary external drive, even choose to install grub on the secondary drive. Grub will be damaged anyway. Workaround 1 is to create a virtual machine and convert virtual disk in standard img file to flash on disk, other is to install it on an other pc and then swap disk. Flashing an oem will be easier